# Delphi: Is there any way to use App Tethering with internet connection?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio Delphi XE8.

Multi-Device Application app tethering components are designed for traditional WiFi and Bluetooth coupling. Does it support also Internet connections?

I would like to try to make small p2p app. I'm using App tethering via Wifi but **I would like to connect App tethering via internet connection.**

how to do that ?

Comment: Yes you can, but you need the IP of the devices to do it. There may also be firewall issues to address. The Embarcadero site gives examples, I think (maybe a skill sprint - I am not sure) but it can definitely be done.

Comment: @Dsm could you give me example? I couldn't find nothing! :(((

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the documentation

> Connecting to Applications Outside Your Subnet
>
> By default, both AutoConnect and DiscoverManagers perform the
>   discovery on the subnet of the local area network (LAN) where the
>   device running your application is. However, you can use their
>   optional parameter Target to override this behavior, and specify an IP
>   address or subnet: To specify an IP address to search for remote
>   managers, specify that IP address as the Target. To specify a subnet
>   of IP addresses, specify an IP address with a 0 as its fourth number.
>   For example, if you specify "192.168.4.0" as the Target, your manager
>   searches the 192.168.4.x subnet for remote managers. Note: You can not
>   specify wider subnets. For example, "192.168.0.0" is not supported.

In other words you need to use the IP address as the optional ATarget parameter of the mentioned calls. The differences to local tethering are minor, which I guess is why there are not many examples.

See [the Embarcadero web site](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Connecting_to_Remote_Applications_Using_App_Tethering) for more details

Comment: This only appears to work with Broadcast (Network), if one tries to use Multicast TIdStack.IsValidIPv4MulticastGroup throws an exception unless the IP range is within Multicast range.

While "Target Syntax" in the wiki says otherwise: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Tether.NetworkAdapter.TTetheringNetworkAdapterMulticast_V4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992103/idtcpclient-and-idtcpserver-exchanging-data-on-desktops-and-not-android

Answer (score 0):

Try VPN connect two device. If your 2 device is same vpn (For ex: Softether , Openvpn). you can discover other device around the world. (Dont forget enable vpn server settings to discover other devices options)